# How to use Python to retrieve HDF5 files

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, hdf5

I have a lot of .dat format files the files internal structure is construct as hdf5 structure it have different groups of data. Now I need some how to retrieve the internal data as a table to view those datas. i tried to used h5py to read the file and put it to pandas dataframe, but unfortunately have some error does anyone can provided some example for me to solve this problem?

```
import h5py
import pandas as pa

with h5py.File("01.dat") as f:
    rdata = f.value[-1]

print rdata

This method also tried, but same error.

with h5py.File('01.dat','r') as hf:
    print('List of arrays in this file: \n', hf.keys())
```

The error below, looks like unable to read the 01.dat file.

```
C:\Anaconda2\python.exe C:/Users/FLU2/PycharmProjects/Dask/Dask.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/FLU2/PycharmProjects/Dask/Dask.py", line 4, in <module>
    with h5py.File("01.dat") as f:
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 260, in __init__
    fid = make_fid(name, mode, userblock_size, fapl, swmr=swmr)
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\h5py\_hl\files.py", line 114, in make_fid
    fid = h5f.create(name, h5f.ACC_EXCL, fapl=fapl, fcpl=fcpl)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 54, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\aroot\work\h5py\_objects.c:2584)
  File "h5py\_objects.pyx", line 55, in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper (C:\aroot\work\h5py\_objects.c:2543)
  File "h5py\h5f.pyx", line 96, in h5py.h5f.create (C:\aroot\work\h5py\h5f.c:1994)
IOError: Unable to create file (Unable to open file: name = '01.dat', errno = 17, error message = 'file exists', flags = 15, o_flags = 502)
```

Appropriate for the help

By the way the internal data structure below, have meta data , result, and time series ,during the time series part it have 30 different groups.
[image]

Comment: It looks like the default mode is to create a file. Try adding 'r' as a parameter to the File() method.

Comment: I have used with h5py.File('01.dat','r') as hf:  but still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to put it in a pandas dataframe, just use `pandas.read_hdf`.

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.read_hdf.html

Comment: Hi i tried to use pandas.read_hdf('01.dat','*')  i just wonder,during the second arguments, if i don't know,how to fill the argument.

Comment: The second argument is the group identifier. If there is one dataset in the file, you don't need the argument. If there are multiple datasets, pass the name of the dataset that you want (the idea is one dataset per pandas dataframe). I'm not sure from your example how your data is structured.

Comment: As you can the my questions above, my datasets is complexity  have 29 Groups, each group have different columns name.   i just want retrieve all groups

Comment: Unfortunately it shows Unable to open/create file '01.dat'   by the way the 29 Groups should be my raster groups, but i do not sure what is my  group identifier

Comment: Are you sure that it's trying to open the right file? Does `os.path.exists("01.dat")` return `True`?

Comment: Yes,i used os.path.exists("01.dat"), it returns True

Comment: `pandas.read_hdf` only works with _**pandas objects**_ stored in HDF5 format, not for generic HDF5 files